# Replace jQuery with PHP or CSS for Customized WordPress wp_nav_menu

Tags: php, menus, jquery

Does anyone know how to build a custom wp_nav_menu layout without using jQuery?

My current menu loads fine, but it causes the whole page to shift. jQuery adds CSS classes to items in the menu after it's loaded to produce drop-down menus.

Is there a way I can replace this jQuery logic with PHP or pure CSS, so it doesn't cause the content layout shift?

wp_nav_menu

```
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <?php wp_nav_menu(array('sort_column'=>'menu_order',
            'menu'=>'Headermenu', 
            'theme_location' => 'primarymenu',
            'container'=>false,
            'items_wrap'=>'%3$s')); ?>
    </ul>
```

jQuery Code (runs in footer)

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$('.navbar-nav li.menu-item-has-children').addClass('dropdown'); 
$('.navbar-nav li.menu-item-has-children > a').addClass('dropdown-toggle'); 
$('.navbar-nav li.menu-item-has-children > a').attr('data-toggle','dropdown'); 
$('.navbar-nav li.menu-item-has-children > a').append('<span class="caret"></span>'); 
$('.navbar-nav li > ul.sub-menu').addClass('dropdown-menu'); 
$('.navbar-nav li > ul.sub-menu').attr('role','menu'); 
</script>
```

Comment: Have you looked at implementing a custom Nav Walker?

Comment: Yes...I go that to work. I'm trying to improve the content layout shift (CLS) and NavWalker didn't seem to do the trick (at least I could remove the jQuery). Looks like flexbox or bootstrap could be causing it.

Comment: I see. We've run into issues with CLS and it's probably due to a combination of other styles being applied first (in your case, bootstrap) and then our styles being applied.

Comment: My outsourced WordPress developers do a shit job of developing for speed, so I end up having to learn this crap in order to clean up their mess.